# NSDate Outputs Wrong Date

Tags: objective-c, format, nsdate, countdown

I am creating a countdown timer to a specific date using `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`. The only problem is that when I run the code with a different format the date messes up. Here is the original code that works great.

```
- (void)updateCountdown {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *startingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-10-08"];
    NSDate *endingDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

    NSInteger days     = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger months   = [dateComponents month];
    NSInteger years    = [dateComponents year];
    NSInteger hours    = [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes  = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds  = [dateComponents second];
    NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Years %ld Months %ld Days %ld Hours %ld Minutes %ld Seconds", (long)days, (long)months, (long)years, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];

    _countdown.text = countdownText;

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

But say I want to remove the years so I change the code like this:

```
- (void)updateCountdown {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *startingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-10-08"];
    NSDate *endingDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

    NSInteger days     = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger months   = [dateComponents month];
    NSInteger hours    = [dateComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes  = [dateComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds  = [dateComponents second];
    NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Months %ld Days %ld Hours %ld Minutes %ld Seconds", (long)days, (long)months, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];

    _countdown.text = countdownText;

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Now all of a sudden the dat is messed up by a whole month. How may I fix this?

Also why is the output 0 years -1months 0 days -2 Hours.. Like why is there (-) in there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are putting your arguments in the wrong order
first you have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Years %ld Months %ld Days %ld Hours %ld Minutes %ld Seconds", (long)days, (long)months, (long)years, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
```

you are entering

- days into a place holder years
- and years into days

then you have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Months %ld Days %ld Hours %ld Minutes %ld Seconds", (long)days, (long)months, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
```

you are entering

- days into a place holder months
- months into place holding for days
  only the last 3 appear to be as you intend

Comment: duh! Thank you so much! Also do you know why the output is -1 Days -2 Hours -1 Minutes? Like do you know why the negatives are there? Thank you so much!

Comment: well the negatives probably relate to it being a countdown. so if I'm counting down to what was yesterday it would be -1 day etc.  Look at your code maybe you are comparing your 2 dates to compare in the wrong order.That's my guess.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought as well except for the fact that the date I have is in the future! lol

Comment: I've not used the method you have to compare dates. I use timeIntervalSinceDate which returns the seconds between 2 refernce dates. I then work out how many year month weeks days hours minutes second that is